# Google colab Pro image loading via opencv is very slow compare with my PC

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

I am ml begginer and now study image processing.
So I was trying to convert images to vectors using opencv on google colab, but it was loading very slowly compared to my PC.
Is this a specification on google colab? If you know anything about this, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.
Thank you!

Code to load images from the drive

```
def get_file(path1, path2, files, img_arrays=[], labels=[]):
    num = 1
    ids = files["id"]
    classes = files.class_num
    for file in ids:
        if num <= 1102:
            print("{}/{}".format(num, len(df_image_id)))
            img = cv2.imread(DATADIR_TRAIN+file)
            img= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            crop_img = CropLemon()(image=img)['image']
            img_array = cv2.resize(crop_img, (224, 224)) 
            img_arrays.append(img_array)
            num += 1
        elif num > 1102:
            print("{}/{}".format(num, len(df_image_id)))
            img = cv2.imread(DATADIR_TEST+file)
            img= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            crop_img = CropLemon()(image=img)['image']
            img_array = cv2.resize(crop_img, (224, 224))
            img_arrays.append(img_array)
            num += 1
            
    for label in classes:
        labels.append(label)
    
    return img_arrays, labels

img_arrays, labels = get_file(DATADIR_TRAIN, DATADIR_TEST, df)
```

I have alredy tried to mount drive and reset runtime